# How to extract an entire JSON object from a mysql database table with column type JSON as an object, not an encoded string?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, object, extract

I have a mysql table called `user`, used to store user information (username, password etc.) It also has a column called `charts` which is of JSON type, and is used to store user-generated charts.

Each chart has a unique id which is used as the key in each key => value pair. The value is a JSON object representing a single chart. So an entry in the `charts` column will look something like this:

```
{
  "18806681bef56a0f99a": {
    "name":"Chart 1",
    "type":"bar"
    ...
  },
  "18806681bef56a0f99b": {
    "name":"Chart 2",
    "type":"line"
    ...
  }
}
```

To save a new chart, I use a PROCEDURE like this:

```
UPDATE user SET charts = JSON_SET(charts, concat('$."', cid, '"'), config) WHERE id = uid
```

where `cid` is chart id, and `uid` is user id. `config` contains the chart data, and is passed to the PROCEDURE as a parameter of type JSON.

This saves the chart data as an object, not as an encoded string.

To extract a single chart I do this:

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(charts, concat('$."', cid, '"')) from user where id = uid
```

where again, `cid` is chart id, and `uid` is user id.

This extracts an object, not an encoded string, so no further decoding is necessary.

I have a page which lists all charts a user has saved, allowing them to view/edit/delete their charts, meaning that I need to extract the entire object from the `charts` column.

This can be achieved either by just extracting the whole column thus:

```
select charts from user where id = uid
```

or using the `JSON_EXTRACT` function like this:

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(charts, '$') from user where id = uid
```

both approaches work perfectly well, but both produce an encoded string, not an object.

I'm using php, so can convert to an object with `json_decode($mysql_result)` or to an array with `json_decode($mysql_result, true)`.

Converting to an array means I can use a simple `foreach` statement, but I have to decode first the main object, and then each value it contains like this:

```
$charts = json_decode($mysql_result, true);

foreach($charts as $id => $chart) {
  $decoded_chart = json_decode($chart);
  echo getTableRow($id, $decoded_chart);
}
```

While this works ok, it seems messy and inefficient to me - it seems strange that there is no built-in mysql function to extract the whole column as an object/array, or am I missing something?

(I'm using mysql 8.0 btw).

**Note**
Because a JSON type column cannot have a default value, when a new user account is created I set the value at `{}`. IE a string. Could this be why a string is always returned? Should I be setting the value to `new stdClass()` instead? Is that even legal?

EDIT
@Barmar `How are you passing an object without encoding it?`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `save_chart`(IN `uid` INT(11), IN `cid` VARCHAR(64), IN `config` JSON)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    COMMENT 'Save a single chart for the specified user'
UPDATE user SET charts = JSON_SET(charts, concat('$."', cid, '"'), config) WHERE id = uid$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The `config` parameter passed to this procedure is a string. It is saved without encoding, and can be extracted without using JSON_UNQUOTE.

Comment: I don't think JSON objects can be passed in binary between the client and server, so strings are always used. The mysql API functions won't automatically convert.

Comment: @Barmar For a single chart, the value passed to the PROCEDURE is a string (from a POST request), but the data type is JSON. It is saved/extracted as an object, not an encoded string. I'm baffled why I can't seem to do the same for the entire object!

Comment: What procedure are you talking about? How are you passing an object without encoding it?

Comment: Note that I'm just talking about the communication between PHP and MySQL. Are you referring to something else that you haven't shown?

Comment: @Barmar  How are you passing an object without encoding it? See edit above

Comment: As I said, I'm just talking about the communication between PHP and MySQL. Are you saying that there's a problem when data passed within MySQL, not going through PHP? Show how you're calling `save_chart()` within MySQL without getting the data from PHP.

Comment: It's hard to understand the full context of the problem from these little snippets. Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

As mysql manual on [json data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) says:

> In MySQL, JSON values are written as strings.

Mysql does store mysql column in a binary format, but for sake of simplicity and interoperability, json values are returned as strings.